# How do I check if the cell value contains only "space"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I could skip if cell value is blank.

```
cell.value == NONE
not cell.value
```

However, this formula can't skip cell containing only "space".

Is there any idea?

Comment: You mean like `cell.value.isspace()`?

Comment: You can use stripe() for remove space.

Comment: There's also regex: `is_empty = bool(re.match('^\s*$', cell.value))`

Answer (score 0):

One way (of many) to do it would be to use [`string.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) on the value to remove leading and trailing whitespaces:

```
val = str(cell.value)
if not val.strip():
    print("No characters")
```

[<sup>Repl.it</sup>](https://repl.it/@esqew/strip-test)

Comment: I think he wants to check for empty cells and cells with empty strings or only whitespace.

Comment: @CharlieClark Any reason why you wouldn't expect this solution to work for both? See my updated [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@esqew/strip-test)

Comment: Sure, if `cell.value` is not a string then you can't call `strip()`

Comment: You have a good point - [`openpyxl`'s `cell.value` method](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html#openpyxl.cell.cell.Cell.value) can return `string`, `float`, `int` or `datetime.datetime`. I've updated my solution to cast to a string before performing `strip()` so that all these types are covered. I've also updated my Repl.it to show this works for all 4 cases.